# Почему вместо значения получаю [Promise] из функции

Tags: javascript, функции, promise

getUserGroups возвращает сгруппированных людей,  getNumberByUserId возвращает некий secretNumber по id,  на выходе нужно получить функцию getUsers, возвращающую массив юзеров такого вида:

```
[ { id: 3, name: 'Alex', secretNumber: 9 } ]
```

```
const getUserGroups = () => {
    const userGroups = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Друзья',
            users: [
                { id: 1, name: 'Anna' },
                { id: 3, name: 'Bob' },
                { id: 4, name: 'V' },
            ],
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Коллеги',
            users: [
                { id: 7, name: 'Alex' },
                { id: 10, name: 'Max' },
                { id: 11, name: 'X' },
                { id: 14, name: 'Steve' },
                { id: 77, name: 'Lisa' },
                { id: 78, name: 'Mike' },
                { id: 81, name: 'Sam' },
                { id: 89, name: 'John' },
            ],
        },
    ];

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(userGroups), 300);
    });
};

const getNumberByUserId = (id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(id ** 2), 3000);
    });
};
const getUsers = async (group) => {
    const promises = group.users.map(async (el) => {
        const secretNumber = getNumberByUserId(el.id);
        return { id: el.id, name: el.name, secretNumber };
    });
    return (await Promise.all(promises)).filter((el) => el.secretNumber % 2 != 0);
}
(async () => {
    const groups = await getUserGroups();
    const results = await Promise.all(groups.map((group) => getUsers(group)))
    console.log(results)
})();
```

У меня приходит массив вида:

```
[ { id: 7, name: 'Alex', secretNumber: [Promise] } ]
```

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос? Что не получается или может есть ошибка?

Comment: const getUsers = async (group) => {
    const promises = group.users.map(async (el) => {
        const secretNumber = getNumberByUserId(el.id);
        return { id: el.id, name: el.name, secretNumber };
    });
    return (await Promise.all(promises)).filter((el) => el.secretNumber % 2 != 0);
}
(async () => {
    const groups = await getUserGroups();
    const results = await Promise.all(groups.map((group) => getUsers(group)))
    console.log(results)
})(); это мое решение

Comment: secretNumber не выъодит { id: 7, name: 'Alex', secretNumber: [Promise] },
    { id: 10, name: 'Max', secretNumber: [Promise] },
    { id: 11, name: 'X', secretNumber: [Promise] },
    { id: 14, name: 'Steve', secretNumber: [Promise] },
    { id: 77, name: 'Lisa', secretNumber: [Promise] },
    { id: 78, name: 'Mike', secretNumber: [Promise] },
    { id: 81, name: 'Sam', secretNumber: [Promise] },
    { id: 89, name: 'John', secretNumber: [Promise] }
  ]
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не дожидаетесь разрешения промиса из функции `getNumberByUserId`, поэтому получаете некорректный ответ.

Добавьте **await** перед вызовом функции `getNumberByUserId` и все заработает

```
const getUsers = async (group) => {
  const promises = group.users.map(async (el) => {
    const secretNumber = await getNumberByUserId(el.id);
    return { id: el.id, name: el.name, secretNumber };
  });
  return (await Promise.all(promises)).filter((el) => el.secretNumber % 2 !== 0);
}
```

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо Вам огромное! Удачи Вам!!!!!!